# Bootstrap swap div for small screen

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a child div with absolute position within parent div.

Parent div contains Bootstrap carousel with relative position.

here is my code

```
 <div class="carousel>
    Carousel goes here
    <div class="col-md-6 SearchBoxHome">
       content goes here
    <div>
  </div>
```

I want to display child div below parent div in small screens.

Here is my jquery code I tried but not working.

```
var screenWidth = $(window).width();
if (screenWidth <= 767) {
   $('.carousel').before($('.SearchBoxHome'));
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Please assist me

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var screenWidth = $(window).width();
if (screenWidth <= 767) {
    var content = $('.SearchBoxHome');
    $('.carousel').before(content);
    $('.carousel').find('.SearchBoxHome').remove();
}
```